# How to display my icon instead of arrow in TreeView?

Tags: java, css, treeview, javafx

I try to replace default arrow icon in TreeView with my icon. The problem is that my icon is cropped although it is only 9x9 pixels. To replace icon I use CSS as suggested on stackoverflow:

```
.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-image: url("plus-icon.gif");
}

.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-image: url("minus-icon.gif");
}
```

But this makes my tiny icon cropped(cut):

[image]

I tried to change this by playing with css and padding but it does not help.

Thank you!

Comment: do you need the `-fx-`? should it not just be `background-image: url("minus-icon.gif");`

Comment: Thanks Pete! This is javafx and css selectors are very similar but with prefix -fx-.

Answer (score 2):

Use 9*9 icons and also given CSS:

```
.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
-fx-shape: null;
-fx-background-color: null;
-fx-background-image: url("plus-icon.gif");
}

.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
-fx-shape: null;
-fx-background-color: null;
-fx-background-image: url("minus-icon.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * the disclosure node is a StackPane, and has as a child another StackPane with style class arrow
 */

.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node,
.tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node{
    -fx-background-image: url("/icons/icons8_stop_sign_100px_1.png"); /* Url of the icon */
    -fx-background-size: 90% 90%; /* Can be `cover` or `100% 100%` ect. */
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center; /* Put the icon in the center */
}

.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node ,
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node {
    -fx-background-image: url("/icons/icons8_new_moon_100px_1.png"); /* Url of the icon */
    -fx-background-size: 90% 90%; /* Can be `cover` or `100% 100%` ect. */
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center; /* Put the icon in the center */
}
```